# Replace specific color with another in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following color as a theme color on my website:

```
#0088cc;
```

How do I replace this color with another one on every element where it is applied throughout the DOM/webpage by changing the body class?

eg.

```
if ($('body').hassClass('black')){
   replace all #0088cc with #000;
}
```

The color represents all different html colors: borders, backgrounds, text-color etc

**UPDATE:**

I see that everyone is not understanding the question correctly:

I have the color #0088cc as my main theme colour. Now various elements inside the body has this color as a text-color, background-color, border-color. So I want to replace EVERY color inside the body's children elements (all elements that has that color defined for something) with a new color, such that I am changing the whole theme...

How would I do that?

Comment: background color or text color?

Comment: any color...there are various elements that use that color: borders, backgrounds, text-color etc

Comment: @DextrousDave i think it is best to use that css switcher i posted for your problem. you will have different themes easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var hexDigits = new Array
            ("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f"); 

    //Function to convert hex format to a rgb color
    function rgb2hex(rgb) {
     rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
     return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
    }

    function hex(x) {
      return isNaN(x) ? "00" : hexDigits[(x - x % 16) / 16] + hexDigits[x % 16];
     }
    $(document).ready(function(){
if ($('body').hassClass('black')){
        $("*").each(function(){
         if(rgb2hex($(this).css("color")) == "#0088cc")
                  $(this).css("color","black");
        });}
    });


Here the demo on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fAMAu/
```

Comment: Hi Arun, could you fix that background color?

Comment: check this at fiddle its been tricky as jquery does not support short-hand css.. :( so the only solution i found is this.
http://jsfiddle.net/fAMAu/32/

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($('body').hassClass('black')){

$(this).css("background","#000"); 
}
```

Comment: Don't think you understand - I do not want to change the color of the body itself, I want to replace ALL colors inside the DOm that has that specific color with another color...On the condition that the body as a specific class

Answer (score 1):

you can use this jquery css switcher plugin to have different themes.
http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/styleswitch/toggle.html

Comment: this will also replace any literal occurrences of the strings. E.g. `<div style="color:#0088cc">#0088CC was the original color but got replaced to #000</div>` will have both occurences replaced

Comment: @RuneFS yes true. i deleted that part.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will set the color to black of all elements that has the black class. However you could then just set that in your CSS and not apply another color to the element

```
  $.fn.replaceCss = function(properties,find,replaceWith, normalize) {
    find = normalize ? normalize(find) : find;
    return this.each(function(){
      var prop,
          self = $(this), 
          css = self.css(properties);

      for(prop in css){
         if(css.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
           val = normalize ? normalize(css[prop]) : css[prop]
           if(val == find){
             css[prop] = replaceWith;
           }
         }
      }
      self.css(css);
      return this;
    });
   };
```

and then you can call it like this

```
$('.black').replaceCss(['color','background-color','another-color-property'],
                       "#0088cc",
                       "#000");
```

However colors might be returned in multiple formats so you might want to normalize them first

```
    $('.black').replaceCss(['color','background-color','another-color-property'],
                       "#0088cc",
                       "#000",
                       function(val){
                          val = val.replace(/\s/g,"");
                          return val == "rgb(0,136,204)" ? "#0088cc" : val
                       });
```

Comment: @undefined yeah I was thinking from the inside of an event handler. It's now fixed. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: Thank you, but what about all other properties of children inside the body: borders, backgrounds etc?

Comment: isn't there a way to do this without using a specific class selector?(such as .black that you are using)

Comment: @dextrousDave The selector is simply the example that you are using. You know your requirements better than I :). Select whatever you wish to select. E.g. If you want all elements `$('*').replaceCss(...)`

Comment: Ok I see, agreed...Why is your code(the second part) giving me syntax errors?

Comment: @DextrousDave I guess because the code was incomplete (since you didn't share the error you got it's hard to tell whether we're talking about the same though). It's complete now and I fixed it so that you can use it in a chained manner as well

Comment: Thank you, but cannot get it to work - see the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fAMAu/28/

Comment: works for me (after remembering to send the properties to the css call). You need to adjust the actual normalize function to your case of course. It was meant as an example and will not work in all cases. you could try and insert a console.log that outputs the prop and the associated val to see how you can adjust the function to your needs

Answer (score 0):

```
    if ($('body').hasClass('black')){ //hope it is a standard hasClass method

      $(this).css("background","#000"); //replace all #0088cc with #000;

      //or for foreground
      $(this).css("color","#000"); //replace all #0088cc with #000;
    }
```

Comment: sorry arun by mistake i changed your code.Please revert my code

Comment: Thank you, but what about all other properties of children inside the body: borders, backgrounds etc?

Answer (score 0):

instead of adding all these css properties seperately, you can club all those properties in a single css class and then add that class using addClass() method(removeClass() if needed)